# Русский текст на изображении

Tags: php

Не отображается русский текст на картинке. Если картинка не в `ANSI` она вообще не показывается.
Пробовал:

```
iconv(mb_convert_encoding("Windows-1251", "ANSI", $str);
```

и

```
iconv("Windows-1251", "ANSI", $str);
```

но не работает.
Я очень начинающий, объясните мне понятно, если решение у проблемы есть.

Comment: а что такое "текст на картинке"?

Comment: похоже Вы путаетесь в понятиях. Используемые Вами команды `iconv` меняют кодировку текста. А ANSI - не кодировка. Вот поддерживаемые php кодировки: http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.supported-encodings.php. Думаю, Вам стоит полностью пересмотреть вопрос

Comment: Просто, когда сохраняешь файл, в выпадающем списке предлагается ANSI, utf-8 и еще пару. Читал на форумах, что проблема у многих возникает. Но, сегодня у меня кириллица отображается, хотя я ничего не менял.